# Using requests.post() to scrape text from web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I'd like to scrape text from a real estate listings webpage. I'm succeeding when I know the URL upfront, but I'm not able to search for a zip code and then scrape the page that results from that search.

```
# I know the URL, and I can scrape data from the page successfully
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/Result/6b1a2c4f-3976-43d8-94a7-5742859f26f1/1' # this URL is the page that follows a zip code search on the 'mlslistings.com' homepage
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
address_raw = list(map(str, tree.xpath('//a[@class="search-nav-link"]//text()'))) # returns addresses found on listings page
```

```
# I want to do the zip code search on the homepage, and scrape the page that follows, but this time get an empty list
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/'
data = {'transactionType': 'buy', 'listing_status': 'Active', 'searchTextType': '', 'searchText': '94618','__RequestVerificationToken': 'CfDJ8K_Ve2wchEZEvUasrULD6jPUmwSLRaolrWoc10T8tMJD8LVSE2c4zMKhNIRwuuwzLZPPsypcZzWaXTHX7Unk1NtVdtAIqIY8AL0DThPMv3xwVMhrzC8UumhLGSXh00oaDHDreGBlWXB2NmRAJi3MbqE'}
post = requests.post(url, data=data)
tree = html.fromstring(post.content)
address_raw = list(map(str, tree.xpath('//a[@class="search-nav-link"]//text()'))) # returns empty list! why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the correct `RequestVerificationToken`, this could be obtained by first requesting the home page.

The following shows a way it could be extracted using BeautifulSoup (feel free to use your own method). Also you need to submit the post request to the correct URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
home_page = sess.get('https://www.mlslistings.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(home_page.content, "html.parser")
rvt = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']
data = {'transactionType': 'buy', 'listing_status': 'Active', 'searchTextType': '', 'searchText': '94618','__RequestVerificationToken': rvt}
search_results = sess.post("https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/ResultPost", data=data)
tree = html.fromstring(search_results.content)
address_raw = list(map(str, tree.xpath('//a[@class="search-nav-link"]//text()'))) # returns addresses found on listings page

print(address_raw)
```

This would give you the addresses as follows:

```
['5351 Belgrave Pl, Oakland, CA, 94618', '86 Starview Dr, Oakland, CA, 94618', '1864 Grand View Drive, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5316 Miles Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '280 Caldecott Ln, Oakland, CA, 94618', '6273 Brookside Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '50 Elrod Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5969 Keith Avenue, Oakland, CA, 94618', '6 Starview Dr, Oakland, CA, 94618', '375 62nd St, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5200 Masonic Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '49 Starview, Oakland, CA, 94618', '4863 Harbord Dr, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5200 Cochrane Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '6167 Acacia Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5543 Claremont Ave, Oakland, CA, 94618', '5283 Broadway Ter, Oakland, CA, 94618', '0 Sheridan Rd, Oakland, CA, 94618']
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. One follow-up question, if you don't mind: I'd like to apply the filter "Property Type: Single Family Residence" accessible under the "More Filters" toolbar item on the results page. Based on element names, I tried adding the key-value pair to the `data` dictionary `data = {'transactionType': 'buy', 'listing_status': 'Active', 'searchTextType': '', 'searchText': '94618','__RequestVerificationToken': rvt, 'custom-control-description': 'Single Family Residence'}` but it's still returning all results, rather than only those marked as "Single Family Residence".

Comment: Try `'property_type':'SingleFamilyResidence'`

Comment: Great. How does one identify the proper `'key': 'value'` names to put into the `data` dictionary?

Comment: I looked at the POST request details using Firefox network tools. Think there were about 20 possible options.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid hardcoding names and values within payload along with grabbing the verification token on the fly, you can try like below. The script is upon lxml parser. Stick to either of them but not both.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

gurl = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/' #url for get requests
purl = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/ResultPost' #url for post requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(gurl)
    root = fromstring(r.text)
    payload = {item.get('name'):item.get('value') for item in root.cssselect('input[name]')}
    payload['searchText'] = '94618'
    res = session.post(purl,data=payload)
    tree = fromstring(res.text)
    address = [item.text.strip() for item in tree.cssselect('.listing-address a.search-nav-link')]
    print(address)
```

Comment: This also works, thank you! Both you and Martin knew to include the `/Search/ResultPost` suffix on the post url. This would not have occurred to me.