# Python post request with Verification token

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've taken a look at many of the other responses on stackoverflow and have watched a few lengthy youtube videos and have yet to stumble on information that would render a solution to my problem. I've used post to login and scrape in other instances, just not when there's been a request token. Perhaps someone can take a look? I'll include the post parameters in a picture. It should be noted that the __RequestVerificationToken changes every time I login.

```
import requests

payload = {
'Email': 'dfo.msdi-idsm.mpo@dfo-mpo.gc.ca',
'Password': 'notrealpassword',
'__RequestVerificationToken': 'RuOal6rKBCWdjNy_15nTS9duFSkM586yGD3LxlWrlGzBB3Noaha9hAm3-tMq9HPvvMstDL8BZ8PvQLPutsreSeGwQOzK1MMwl76Q2c7n1zo1',
}

URL = 'http://gisd.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/DFO_WebServiceManager/Account/Login'
Pacific = 'https://gisd.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/DFO_WebServiceManager/FGP?SearchString=Pacific'

with requests.session() as c:
    c.post(URL, data=payload)
    r = c.get(Pacific)
    print r.content
```

[image]

Comment: Currently, if you are hitting with this payload so you are not getting logged into site?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Make this request via browser and copy curl of that request. Analyze that curl request by removing parameters one by one and filtering that what headers, cookies are being required by the site other than this

Answer (score 1):

That token looks like a CSRF token. You should add the cookie containing the `__RequestVerificaionToken` to the request and see if it works.

```
import requests

payload = {
'Email': 'dfo.msdi-idsm.mpo@dfo-mpo.gc.ca',
'Password': 'notrealpassword',
'__RequestVerificationToken': 'RuOal6rKBCWdjNy_15nTS9duFSkM586yGD3LxlWrlGzBB3Noaha9hAm3-tMq9HPvvMstDL8BZ8PvQLPutsreSeGwQOzK1MMwl76Q2c7n1zo1',
}

cookies = {
'__RequestVerificationToken': 'your token',
}

URL = 'http://gisd.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/DFO_WebServiceManager/Account/Login'
Pacific = 'https://gisd.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/DFO_WebServiceManager/FGP?SearchString=Pacific'

with requests.session() as c:
    c.post(URL, data=payload, cookies=cookies)
    r = c.get(Pacific)
    print r.content
```

Comment: Yah, I had tried putting the token in as a cookie.. Didn't seem to work. It's a head scratcher for sure since I've logged into other pages before easily..

Comment: @dpalm from your screenshot, the token and the cookie seems to have different values. Can you confirm that you have put their respective values in? Also, do add their respective headers too.

Comment: I half follow you as I'm not sure how that would all look. Are those included in the payload or separate?

Comment: @dpalm The token in the cookie shown in your screenshot starts with L0R, whereas the token in the payload (request body) starts with RuO. They are of different values.

Comment: every time you login the request verification token changes. Unfortunately I have yet to figure this one out..

Comment: @dpalm You could send a GET request after login to take the token value then put it into the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time but for others like me looking for the same issue, you can look at [@Martin Evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56211127) for perspective.